# How to get closest geo position within radius?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am running a rails 4 application with postgis.
In order to get closest points I have the following sql

```
 SELECT * FROM geo_name_cities 
 WHERE ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_Geomfromtext('POINT(11.75292 47.42321)', 1000))
 ORDER BY ST_Distance(lonlat, ST_Geomfromtext('POINT(11.75292 47.42321)',1000))
 limit 5;
```

For some reason I do get the following error:

```
ERROR: function st_geomfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add  
explicit type casts.
Character: 57
```

I don't see a difference to the postgis doc

```
 ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)');
```

Comment: Is your database spatially enabled i.e., `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`?

Comment: yes it is but on another scheme

Comment: That's probably the issue. Is the other schema in `show search_path`?

Comment: in rails I have the following config   schema_search_path: public,postgis and it is working, but not on the db command line. Now you are right show search path is not showing the postgis schema. I just added postgis as additional search path but nothing changed after restarting the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PostGIS was installed on to a schema that is not on the `search_path` (e.g., in `postgis`), either the functions need to be provided in full (e.g., `postgis.st_geomfromtext(...)`) or the `search_path` needs to be updated. This can be done per session:

```
SET search_path = postgis, public;
```

To permanently alter the `search_path` for a database:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_database SET search_path = postgis, public;
```

Or for a user:

```
ALTER USER postgres SET search_path = postgis, public;
```